# ¿Cómo revertir Ctrl + z en nvim?, Window me bloquea toda la terminal

Tags: nvim

Cuando presiono `Ctrl + z` en `nvim` aparece `^Z` en la parte inferior derecha y no me deja escribir nada, en ningún lado ni siquiera en la línea de comandos; uso `windows terminal` en `window`. He leído que no es un problema de `nvim` sino del terminal y que presionando `fg` se resolvía; pero no me deja escribir nada en la línea de comandos. espero que alguien me pueda dar alguna idea de como revertir esto, Gracias...

Comment: ¿Que tiene que ver nvim con [tag:python], [tag:c#], [tag:c++], [tag:nodejs] o [tag:linux]?

Comment: Pues estoy invocando a los pros, que seguro programan en la terminal; si pongo solo `terminal` o `consola` no muchos verán mi pregunta.

Comment: El uso que das a las etiquetas es incorrecto, las etiquetas no se añaden a una pregunta para darle visibilidad si no para clasificar el ámbito de la pregunta. Que una persona conozca [tag:python], [tag:c#], [tag:c++], [tag:nodejs] o [tag:linux] no implica que tenga conocimientos de nvim.

Comment: Correcto; pero solo lo hago para tener comentarios que me ayuden, cuando tenga la solución editaré la pregunta y pondré las etiquetas correctas...

Comment: ¿Correcto? No. No es correcto usar mal el sitio deliberadamente con la excusa de "*ya lo arreglaré*" O_o

Comment: Bueno, creo que se ofendieron; la próxima vez que corrija también seré estricto con los recién llegados. --eliminaré la pregunta después que lo leas--

Comment: Esto no tiene nada que ver con ofenderse si no con usar bien el sitio, si te cuesta usar bien las herramientas a tu alcance, tal vez no sean las herramientas adecuadas para ti.

Comment: Lamento decirlo pero paper tiene razon... Si hubieses puesto PHP en las etiquetas, aparezco yo, y no puedo darte una ayuda, dado que es otra cosa... Si, el resto de ellos usa terminal, pero no por ello saben de NVIM. Es como buscar un libro de terror y que lo hayan dejado en humor, por que a alguien se le ocurrio que a otra persona le podría llamar la atención que este en ese lugar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

la terminal de linux no reconoce CTRL + Z,CTRL + C,CTRL + V, siendo que este tipo de atajos son usados para cancelar operaciones y otras cosas en linux, por lo cual siendo que nvim y vim actuara de manera linux, para regresar cambios debes usar la tecla U o configurarla por tu cuenta en el .vimrc.
aqui te dejo un guia: [atajos de vim](https://geekland.eu/atajos-de-teclado-y-comandos-para-usar-vim-eficientemente/)